# My project is not appearing in the Klov report

Tags: c#, reporting, specflow, extentreports

I used the below lines of code to generate klov reports:

```
public static void InitializeReporter()
{

    var klov = new KlovReporter();

    klov.InitMongoDbConnection("localhost", 27017);
    klov.ProjectName = "VplatesAutomationProjectTest";
    klov.ReportName = "Test" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
    klov.KlovUrl = "http://localhost";
}
```

mongodb command prompt shows the below without any error or exception

```
2018-08-08T16:42:47.564+1000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55217 #6 (3 connections now open)
2018-08-08T16:43:06.987+1000 I NETWORK  [conn6] end connection 127.0.0.1:55217 (2 connections now open)
2018-08-08T16:51:34.154+1000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:56209 #7 (3 connections now open)
2018-08-08T16:51:41.372+1000 I NETWORK  [conn7] end connection 127.0.0.1:56209 (2 connections now open)
2018-08-08T16:58:46.168+1000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:56935 #8 (3 connections now open)
2018-08-08T16:58:57.926+1000 I NETWORK  [conn8] end connection 127.0.0.1:56935 (2 connections now open)
```

When i hit localhost on the browser the page opens but there is no project in project the selection drop down

Comment: Please post complete Extent code.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining klov as a KlovReporter.
You need also to attachReporter, hope it helps :)

```
    KlovReporter klovReporter = new KlovReporter();
    klovReporter.initMongoDbConnection("172.0.0.1", 27017);
    klovReporter.setProjectName("ProjectName");
    klovReporter.setReportName("reportFileName");
    klovReporter.setKlovUrl("http://172.0.0.1");
    extent.attachReporter(klovReporter);
```

Comment: There is no difference using var klovReporter = new KlovReporter();